# Spring security creates infinite loop of 301 and 302 redirects to login page

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have an application with Spring Boot 2.0.4.RELEASE, where some of urls are public, some others require authentication. It works fine, but when I've checked it with this tool -> https://www.redirect-checker.org/ when I'm checking my homepage or any subpage I get:

```
Result
https://www.myurl.com/     302      https://www.myurl.com/index     302      http://www.myurl.com/index     301 Moved Permanently     https://www.myurl.com/index     302      https://www.myurl.com/index     302      http://www.myurl.com/index     301 Moved Permanently     https://www.myurl.com/index     302      https://www.myurl.com/index     302      http://www.myurl.com/index     301 Moved Permanently     https://www.myurl.com/index
```

...

Here's my configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableScheduling
public class ApplicationConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private static final String[] GET_PUBLIC_URLS = {
            "/",
            "/resources/**",
            ...
    };
    private static final String[] POST_PUBLIC_URLS = {
            "/password_reset",
            ...
    };

@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .cors().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(GET, GET_PUBLIC_URLS).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(POST, POST_PUBLIC_URLS).permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .successHandler(new AuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
                        //do nothing
                    }
                })
                .loginPage("/index")
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/user_account", true)
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }
...
}
```

I've also added additional settings in application.config

```
server.tomcat.protocol-header=x-forwarded-proto
server.use-forward-headers=true
```

In general that's all I could find on StackOverflow to solve my problem, but I'm still having redirect problem. Am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
Configuration was not correct. Here's a good one:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .cors().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(GET, GET_PUBLIC_URLS).anonymous()
                .antMatchers(POST, POST_PUBLIC_URLS).anonymous()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/index")
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/user_account", true)
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }
```

The problem was that public urls are public for everyone, so .anyRequest().authenticated() was incorrect, should be anonymous() in my case.